# Azure IoT Hub Deployment: Default eventHub endpoint 'operationsMonitoringEvents' is missing

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub

Recently I had issues to deploy an IoT Hub. I used an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template that worked so far but then resulted in the error `Default eventHub endpoint 'operationsMonitoringEvents' is missing`. Below what you have to add to achieve a successfull deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the eventHub endpoint 'operationsMonitoringEvents'

```
"operationsMonitoringEvents": {
    "retentionTimeInDays": "[parameters('opMonRetentionTimeInDays')]",
    "partitionCount": "[parameters('opMonPartitionCount')]",
    "path": "[concat(parameters('iotHubName'),'-operationmonitoring')]",
    "endpoint": "[parameters('opMonEndpoint')]"
}
```

The endpoint can be found e.g. via the portal here

[image]

Additionally you can configure operations monitoring e.g. via

```
"operationsMonitoringProperties": {
    "events": {
        "None": "None",
        "Connections": "None",
        "DeviceTelemetry": "None",
        "C2DCommands": "None",
        "DeviceIdentityOperations": "None",
        "FileUploadOperations": "None",
        "Routes": "None"
    }
}
```

Edit: as mentioned by [Dipti Mamidala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8831039/dipti-mamidala) it is also enough to add only

```
"operationsMonitoringEvents": {
    "retentionTimeInDays": "[parameters('opMonRetentionTimeInDays')]",
    "partitionCount": "[parameters('opMonPartitionCount')]"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must have to add the following section in IoT Hub ARM Template :

```
 "operationsMonitoringEvents": {
            "retentionTimeInDays": "[parameters('retentionDays')]",
            "partitionCount": "[parameters('partitionCount')]"

          }
```

The above section is not required to add in ARM Template when creating new IoT Hub but if it is not added in ARM Template and deploy to portal, it will add the above section at time of deployment.

So when we do the incremental deployment with the same ARM Template(Which does not contain the above section), it will compare with the existing ARM Template deployed on portal and with the current deploying one which cause to the above error.

So we also face this error in past and resolved by adding the above code in ARM Template.